# how to define a vector<boost::mutex> in C++ ?

Tags: c++, boost, vector, mutex

I want to define a vector with boost::mutex like :

```
  boost::mutex myMutex ;
  std::vector< boost::mutex > mutexVec; 
  mutexVec.push_back(myMutex);
```

But, I got error on Linux:

/boost_1_45_0v/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:33: error: âboost::mutex::mutex(const boost::mutex&)â is private
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/ext/new_allocator.h:104: error: within this context

I cannot find a solution by searching online.

thanks

Comment: What is `mutexVec.push_back(myMutex);` expected to do?

Answer (score 9):

You could use a boost [pointer container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html):

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>

boost::ptr_vector<boost::mutex> pv;
pv.push_back(new boost::mutex);
```

A ptr_vector takes ownership of its pointers so that they are deleted when appropriate without any of the overhead a smart pointer might introduce.

Comment: +1 -- note still though that inserting a mutex into said container invalidates thread safety of the container while the insert is going on....

Comment: @BillyONeal "_invalidates thread safety of the container_" what thread safety?

Comment: @curiousguy: With STL containers, multiple readers are typically safe. Multiple writers are not.

Answer (score 5):

The copy constructor is private. You aren't supposed to copy a mutex.

Instead use:

```
boost::mutex *myMutex = new boost::mutex();
std::vector< boost::mutex *> mutexVec; 
mutexVec.push_back(myMutex);
```

and if you don't want to manage the memory yourself use a `boost::shared_ptr<boost::mutex>` instead of `boost::mutex*`

Comment: Please don't put raw pointers in STL containers. That's like killing puppies. Note though that `shared_ptr` has threading characteristics you need to pay attention to...

Comment: @BillyONeal "_threading characteristics you need to pay attention to..._" like being inefficient?

Comment: @curiousguy: Depends on your particular implementation. Sometimes it'll just be inefficient. Sometimes it'll cause race conditions or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

`boost::mutex` cannot be stored in a `vector` because it is not copy constructable. As mentioned in PeterT's answer, it is possible to store pointers to the mutex inside the `vector` instead, you really should probably reconsider a design which relies on such things. Keep in mind `vector` itself does not have any threading requirements, and trying to do anything modifying the vector will not be a thread safe operation.

Comment: "_does not have any threading requirements_" what do you mean?

Comment: @curiousguy: I mean the standard doesn't say anything about what operations affect threading. There are literally no requirements in the standard whatsoever.

Comment: There is no requirement that you can call two functions at the same time in different threads either...

Comment: @curiousguy: Did I say otherwise? Generally when something isn't documented as thread safe you have to assume it's thread unsafe.

Comment: So you cannot do anything safely in a multithread program. Not even call two different functions, not even use an operator. Nothing.

Comment: @curiousguy: That depends on your platform, compiler, libraries, etc. Thread safety must be designed for, not assumed. Threading characteristics need to be documented because even when one has access to source code, threading characteristics are not obvious. (In this respect it's similar to exception safety)